# Child attribute changes from different view controller are not reflecting in parent attribute in other View Controller - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an attribute which has a relationship with a sub attribute which has a property as follows :

- to Many
- Cascade Delete Rule

When I navigate to different View Controller, Say B, I am deleting records of the subAttribute and inserting once again with some fresh new records.

And again when I come back to View Controller A and try to insert some Data on the above sub Attribute , it says

`"Dangling reference to .null object"`.

Need some help on what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoreData: "Dangling reference to an invalid object." error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003648/coredata-dangling-reference-to-an-invalid-object-error)

Comment: Absolutely right , Whenever i insert data into CoreData Need to make sure that its not duplicating the data inside DB.

Comment: So you managed to solve it?

Comment: Nope , there seems to be sort of design flaw when they are inserting.